# Set value of a model field that is not part of model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model like this

```
class Income(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    remitted = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

I have a form like this

```
class EditIncomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Income
        fields = ("value", )

        def clean_value(self):
           value = self.cleaned_data["value"]
            if self.value < self.remitted:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Error message")
            return value
```

Now in the modelform, how do I update the value of the `remitted` field?
I can't seem to be able to access the `remitted` field this way. I'm on Django 2.0

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with whether the field is on the form or not.

You're doing two things wrong; firstly, you're trying to access `self.remitted` instead of `self.cleaned_data['remitted']`; and secondly, `remitted` won't have been cleaned at the point that `clean_value` is called.

To access data from multiple fields, override the main `clean()` method instead:

```
 def clean(self):
      value = self.cleaned_data["value"]
      remitted = self.cleaned_data["remitted"]
      if value < remitted:
          self.add_error("value", "Error message")
```

Comment: as i understand the `remitted` is absent in the clean data

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: `fields = ("value", )`

Comment: But that doesn't have anything to do with what's in the cleaned_data, it just determines what fields are saved to the instance.

Comment: o thanks, i confused in my mind with the drf serializers

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'll try it out when I have time. But one question. Do I specifically have to use the `self.add_error("value", "Error message")` or I should use `forms.ValidationError`?

Comment: In the general clean method, raising a ValidationError will cause it not to be associated with any particular field, so it'll display in `form.non_field_errors`. It depends on whether that matters to you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the error to the 'value' field in the form. Question now is how do I raise the error in the template to alert the user that something is amiss.

Comment: @Bear Brown
I guess we've both learned something new today about form field cleaning. Cheers

Comment: Okay. I used `{{ form.errors }} ` and it didn't show up

As an aside. Could you advise on how to read Django'and source code?

Comment: If the error is not showing up, there is something wrong with your view and/or template; you should post them.

Comment: The modelform is not calling the `clean()` method. Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I did some reading about [Validation on a ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) from the docs and finally I was able to raise the error in the form. Full form code below.

[This section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method) in particular proved to be what I needed. It says:

> A model form instance attached to a model object will contain an
>   instance attribute that gives its methods access to that specific
>   model instance.

```
class EditIncomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Income
        fields = ("value", )

    def clean(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['value']
        remitted = self.instance.remitted # access other model field.
        if value <= remitted:
            self.add_error("value", "Error message.")
```